# Использовать Select в async

Tags: c#, linq

если не сложно тыкните меня в ошибку, не могу понять как использовать селект в асинхронном методе...
Код интерфейса:

```
public interface IUserService
    {       
        Task<List<User>> GetIdentity();
    }
```

сервис:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
    {
        DBUserContext db;
        public UserService(DBUserContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        }       

        public async Task<List<User>> GetIdentity()
        {
            return await db.Users.Include(x => x.UserFriends).ThenInclude(x => x.User).ToListAsync();

        }       
    }
```

и сам контроллер:

```
[HttpGet, Route("getidenti"), Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {           
            UserViewModel userdb = userService.GetIdentity().Select( c =>  new UserViewModel        
            {

                Id = c.Id,
                UserName = c.UserName,
                Password = c.Password,
                LastName = c.LastName,
                Friends = c.UserFriends.Select(x => new UserFriendsViewModel(x)).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        return Ok(userdb);
        }
```

ругается на селект, мол не может он работать с асинхронным методом, если делаю все части без асинка, но все получается отлично и все работает, но как я понимаю, желательно чтоб все было асинковым, и так не могу уже 3-й час ничего найти...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дождитесь таска и выполните Select:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{   
    var users = await userService.GetIdentity();

    var usersVm = users
        .Select(c =>  new UserViewModel        
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            UserName = c.UserName,
            Password = c.Password,
            LastName = c.LastName,
            Friends = c.UserFriends.Select(x => new UserFriendsViewModel(x)).ToList()
        })
        .ToList();

    return Ok(usersVm);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо ребят!! на такой мелочи прокололся...

Answer (score 2):

Вы не дожидаетесь выполнения GetIdentity, ибо он возвращает Task>, а не List

Надо переписать вот так

```
UserViewModel userdb = (await userService.GetIdentity()).Select(c =>
```

В целом я не знаю контекста, но вам не нужно в GetIdentity делать ToListAsync. Ибо получается вы лишние действия делаете в памяти( в данном случае мало что изменится вроде, но так делать не стоит). Обычно делается так:

```
public IQueryable<User> GetIdentity()
    {
        return db.Users.Include(x => x.UserFriends).ThenInclude(x => x.User);

    }     
// И теперь можете писать
UserViewModel userdb = await userService.GetIdentity().Select( c =>  new UserViewModel        
        {

            Id = c.Id,
            UserName = c.UserName,
            Password = c.Password,
            LastName = c.LastName,
            Friends = c.UserFriends.Select(x => new UserFriendsViewModel(x)).ToList()
        }).ToListAsync();
```

Тобишь раньше GetIdentity лез в базу, доставал все в память, а потом вы делаете что хотите(и все последующие действия будут в памяти, хотя часть из них должна быть в запросе. Например если вы захотите сделать OrderBy после GetIdentity, то это будет выполнено в памяти, а не в запросе к бд, что намного дольше, особенно если данных дофига).

А теперь GetIdentity просто обернул в себя начальное построение запроса. На этом этапе он еще не идет в базу, пока вы явно не обратитесь к переменной или не вызовите что-то типа ToList(), Result, ToListAsync(пока вы явно не обратитесь к данным)

Comment: Только из GetIdentity тогда нужно выбросить всю асинхронщину: `public IQueryable<User> GetIdentity() => db.Users.Include(x => x.UserFriends).ThenInclude(x => x.User);`

Comment: @Vlad да, я случайно оставил.